# adobe livecycle designer es2 percentages

Tags: adobe, field, percentage, livecycle

I need to make some percentage fields, but I cannot make them like I need.
In total there will be 5 fields, with user input data format `XXX%`.

- The first issue it that the fileds in total should sum `100%` else an error message should appear.
- The second issue, has to do with field format. The user should input 5 and the field should make it `005%.` 
  Accordingly, user input `10 -> 010%` and finally `100 -> 100%`
  Of course, the maximum input number should be the "100".

Any help?!?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I assume the sum field total is calculated automatically using the calculate event, in that case you can use Javascript to display an error if all the field are filled and the total is not equal to 100.

For the dislpay, you need to use patterns, see documentation at : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/designerHelp/index.htm?content=000490.html

For data validation, you can use validate event on the fields or manually check the value on the exit event of the field.